# How do you get a different item on BottomNavigation to be selected at the startup

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer

im relatively new to AS. Im using BottomNavigationView with several items in it. Basically I want a different item to be selected when opening the App, because the left item (first one in the XML - file) is the one selected by default.

I put the following snippet in the onCreateView Method of my Fragment:

```
bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_bar)
bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(0).setChecked(true)
```

The XML of the NavigationBar:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:itemIconSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

I somehow keep receiving this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: view.findViewById(R.id.nav_bar) must not be null

Does someone knows an answer to this?
Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to do this way by replacing both of the lines. This is based on Kotlin:

```
        bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id. nav_bar
```